# Run Script in Terminal On Start Up

Tags: cron, autostart

I'm trying to create a script on my Ubuntu machine which should run in the terminal some minutes after startup:

"run.sh"

```
sleep 10
sudo gnome-terminal --working-directory="/home/joan/Desktop/Server/" --command="java -Xmx4096M -Xms4096M -jar server.jar nogui"
```

I've tried cron, but it doesn't allow to create any windows to use as a console or output.

Cron file line:

```
30 11   * * *   root    sh /home/joan/Desktop/Server/run.sh
```

Any alternatives?

Comment: Could you explain what your actual objective is here? Why do you need it to run in a terminal? Do you want to have the terminal window open so you can interact with it, or do you just need to be able to see the output? Why are you running this as `root`? And, specifically, why run the terminal as root instead of the command?

Comment: How do you know anyone is logged in and is running a desktop when the cron job starts? Do you have multiple users on the system?

Comment: The idea is to automatically start the server without any input. And the script to open the server seems to require a terminal tha'ts why I run the command in a gnome-terminal, and yes, I want to be able to later be able to interact with it. Also the script I'm editing is /etc/crontab, and I've tried to run the command with and without user. @terdon

Comment: Only one user that automatically logs in! @Kusalananda

Comment: So basically at night it shutsdown, in the morning it turns on, and I want to be able to run a script that restarts the server to make the process fully automatic without me having to do it manually everyday.

Comment: Starting the terminal itself with root privileges doesn't seem right. At best, that should be for the application, surely?